# String.replace then change the color of the replaced word

Tags: android

```
String string = "Change this color"
string.replace("this", "");
```

How to change the color of the word "this" by replace() method?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`replace()` cannot be used to change the appearance of a string, [Neha's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46508550/2035645) answer is also correct, but a better way to do it is using the Spannable class, following function changes the color of String `search` in String `text` and returns a spannable object,

```
 private Spannable getSpannableText(String text, String search, Context context) {
    int initialOffset = text.toLowerCase().indexOf(search.toLowerCase(), 0);
    Spannable spannableText = new SpannableString(text);
    for (int ofs = 0; ofs < text.length() && initialOffset != -1; ofs = initialOffset + 1) {
        initialOffset = text.toLowerCase().indexOf(search.toLowerCase(), ofs);
        if (initialOffset == -1) {
            break;
        } else {
            //highlighting with color red
            spannableText.setSpan(new ForegroundColorSpan(ContextCompat.getColor(context, R.color.red)), initialOffset, initialOffset + search.length(), Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
        }
    }
    return spannableText;
}
```

You can then use it as follows,

```
 tv_text.setText(getSpannableText("Change this color","this", context), TextView.BufferType.SPANNABLE);
```

Comment: Neha's answer is correct though but i'm not satisfied the way and the one thing is the HTML.fromhtml() is deprecated.